# How to use Code org creating simple program without using a bunch of OnEvents

Tags: code.org

using code.org i need to be able to have a user click on a button that takes them to another screen without using OnEvent(s) constantly, can anyone help me out? Newb here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What did you examine yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer as I'm completely new to any type of programming. My best answer is: I don't  want the code full of just OnEvents as just doesn't look right. Here's what I came up with today, any thoughts?  onEvent("StartGame", "click", function()  {
    setScreen("CharacterScrn"
}) ;
onEvent("MANbtn", "click", function() {
onEvent (startBtn, "click", function(). {
     SetScreen("screen1")

Comment: Hi @UnsureNovice; what do you mean onEvents "just don't look right"? Based on what you've said here, that seems like exactly the right way to go about doing what you want to do. Do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function with a value for button and string and put a callback inside

```
function event(button,input_type, screen) {
    onEvent(button, input_type, function() {
        setScreen(screen);
    });
}
```